# call a function using variable in function name

Tags: php, function

```
foreach($arr as $el){
    $what= $el->what;
    if($what == 'img'){get_img();}
    elseif($what == 'video'){get_video();
    elseif($what == 'something'){get_something();} 
}
```

How to say the above shortly, like this:

```
 get_$what();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as in https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

```
$func = 'foo';
$func();        // This calls foo()
```

so in your case:

```
foreach($arr as $el){
    $what= $el->what;
    $funcname = 'get_'.$what;
    $funcname();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use parentheses

```
<?php

function ab(){echo 'ho';}
$foo='video';
('get_'.$foo)();
```

Comment: I already answered this question once. If I could only find where.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the function name into a variable and then call that function dynamically by adding `()` to the variable. ( not sure if i said this right )

```
$yourFunction = 'get_';
$yourFunction .= 'img';

$value = $yourFunction();
// will execute get_img();
```

[here is a fiddle to play with](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6306862742f9ac2410651b673eef706fe75e9992)

Answer (score 1):

```
 function get_id(){
        echo "id";
       }
    function get_d(){
        echo "d";
        }

      $id='id';
      $fun='get_'.$id;
      $fun();
```

> outputs:      id